# How to format TypeScript code in Netbeans 8?

Tags: ubuntu, typescript, netbeans-8

I have Netbeans 8.0.2 with installed netbeanstypescript.nbm plugin. Javascript code formating well with Alt+Shift+F, but it is not working for TypeScript code. How to do it?

Comment: looking at the plugin code I see there is already autoformatting (on enter, semi-colon etc). are you sure your document is not already formatted? :)

Comment: I'm sure, and Alt+Shift+F has no any effect after any code change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems with access (Ubuntu). I had ran Netbeans under `sudo`. It helped.
After that I changed owner of Netbean's local files:

```
sudo chown -R my_user:my_user ~/.netbeans
sudo chown -R my_user:my_user ~/.cache/netbeans
```

After that I run Netbeans under *my_user*.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work, so please file an issue at the plugin issuetracker

https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/issues